# How to delete records in hive table by spark-sql?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I try to delete records in hive table by spark-sql, but failed. Follow is message:

```
spark-sql> delete from jgdy
         > ;
2022-03-17 04:13:13,585 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.internal.ss.authz.settings.applied.marker does not exist
2022-03-17 04:13:13,585 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.jdbc.timeout does not exist
2022-03-17 04:13:13,585 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.stats.retries.wait does not exist
Error in query: DELETE is only supported with v2 tables.
```

Who can show me how to delete? Or is there any configurations I need to do?
thanks